# Обработка векторых изображений с помощью php

Tags: php, вектор, обработка-изображений

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в php правильно обрабатывать векторные изображения. Можно ли вообще такое сделать впринципе? Например нужно изменить размеры визитки, т.е. векторного изображения (eps), главное чтобы изображение не растеризировалось. Читал много документации по imagemagick, искал различные библиотеки, но так ничего и не нашел.